# Последовательность событий jQuery

Tags: jquery, события, javascript

Имеется блок div, в котором ссылка.
Когда происходит клик по ссылке, вызывается и события клика для блока.
Как разграничить события?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы столкнулись со всплытием событий (event bubbling) - механизм DOM-модели, при котором событие, вызванное на каком-то элементе, распространяется на родительские элементы в иерархии DOM (или "всплывает").

"Всплытие" происходит всегда - это стандартное поведение. Но есть возможность в обработчике остановить "всплытие" и не пустить событие дальше вверх по иерархии. Если вы используете jQuery, то используйте функцию `stopPropagation()` в объекте `event`:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // TODO
});
```

Пример практически полностью взят из документации: [http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

---

Более подробно про всплытие событий и про то, как его правильно остановить в чистом javascript, смотрите здесь: [Всплывающие события (Bubbling)](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/events/intro#vsplyvayushchie-sobytiya-bubbling)